# Ajuda com java RMI, como utilizar o método rebind e fazer lookup com a classe cliente?

Tags: java, rmi

Estou realizando um trabalho na faculdade no qual me sinto perdido. Eu não sei como indicar o servidor com o método `rebind` e fazer `lookup` com a classe cliente. Gostaria que vocês pudessem olhar o código que estou escrevendo para ver se estou no caminho certo e ensinar como utilizar o método `rebind`, fazer `lookup` e me indicar materiais de estudo. Desde já obrigado.

**Enunciado do trabalho:**

> Você deve descrever e construir um sistema simples, utilizando a tecnologia RMI, para informar ao cliente a data e a hora atual.
>
> Com base na interface, construa um cliente que faça o `lookup` por um serviço disponibilizado pelo servidor, utilizando JNDI. Este serviço, deve retornar a data e a hora devidamente formatadas. Em seguida, o cliente deve imprimir as informações na console.

Interface `InterfaceServidorDataEHora`:

```
package javaee_tp1;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface InterfaceServidorDataEHora extends Remote
{
    public String getHoraData() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Classe `ServidorDataEHora`:

```
package javaee_tp1;
import java.rmi.Remote.*;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class ServidorDataEHora extends UnicastRemoteObject implements InterfaceServidorDataEHora
{
    public ServidorDataEHora() throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println("ServidorDataHora iniciado... :)");
    }

    @Override
    public String getHoraData() throws RemoteException 
    {
        GregorianCalendar atual = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        SimpleDateFormat formatacao = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' de 'MMMMM' de 'yyyy' - 'HH':'mm'h'");
        return formatacao.format(atual.getTime());
    }
}
```

Classe `RegistradorServidor`:

```
package javaee_tp1;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RegistradorServidor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Registrando Servidor no RMI.....");
        try 
        {
            Naming.rebind("ServidorDataEHora_0", new ServidorDataEHora());
        } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro de registro \n"+ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Ainda não escrevi a classe cliente, pois acho que tem algo errado nas classes acima.

Comment: Oi. Tirei a tag java-ee porque sua questão não é sobre Java EE afinal de contas. O RMI, na verdade reside no Java SE, e não há mais nada na sua questão que seja específico do Java EE. É verdade que o RMI é usado bastante por debaixo dos panos pelo EJB no Java EE, mas aqui você o está utilizando diretamente, então não há porque aplicar esta tag.

Comment: Tudo bem sem problemas, obrigado por editar :)